# How to make an condition case with time type in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some problem, I want make some query using case condition with time in sql, but I got some error anyone can describe what code I have been wrong?

Query :

```
SELECT `no_reg`,`time`
CASE
WHEN `time` BETWEEN '06:15't AND '11:59't THEN 'Time_In'
END AS time_in
FROM raw_attendance
```

Error :

[image]

and `time` is `time` data type

Comment: which sql? what database?

Comment: mysql database, sorry my question is not detail

Comment: @Alif... instead of apologizing, why not add some details? You mentioned you "*got some error*"... **what** error is that?

Comment: What is the datatype of `time`?

Comment: I already edit my question sorry for confusing

Comment: That error is caused by missing a comma after `\`time\``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `no_reg`,`time`,
CASE
WHEN `time` BETWEEN '06:15't AND '11:59't THEN 'Time_In'
END AS time_in
FROM raw_attendance
```

Run this, this should work. You missed a Comma after time field. Also you have no ELSE condition, which should be.